# Mysql update seems to be working but throwing statement closed error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, exception

The below java code throws this error when I run it: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed. What is curious is that the intended function of the code is being done. The password does indeed change, indicating that the statement did execute. The "failed" output at the end seems to be indicating that the code had an exception somewhere, though. Any ideas?

```
private void ChangeSQLPassword(String userName,char[] pass) {
        Connection conn = null;
        String hashed = "";
        String salt = "";
        String concat = "";
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PM";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "Tempuser", "temppass");
            System.out.println("Database connection established");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Cannot connect to database server");
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    System.err.println("Connection not null...");
                    salt = getSalt();
                    hashed = sha256(pass,salt);
                    Statement sta3 = conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = sta3.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM pmusers"); //Select users
                    System.out.println(userName + " " + new String(pass));
                    while (rs.next() == true) { //Loop through results
                        if (rs.getString("username").equals(userName)) {
                            concat = concat.concat("UPDATE pmusers SET Hashed = '" + hashed + "', Salt = '" + salt + "' WHERE Username = '" + userName +"';");
                            sta3.executeUpdate(concat);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) { /* ignore close errors */
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.err.println("Failed.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

static String sha256(char[] input, String Salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] result;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        mDigest.update(Salt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        result = mDigest.digest(String.valueOf(input).getBytes("UTF-8"));
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((result[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.out.println("Encoding failed.");
    }

    String hashed = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(String.valueOf(sb).getBytes());

    return hashed;
}

private static String getSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
    //Always use a SecureRandom generator
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
    //Create array for salt
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    //Get a random salt
    sr.nextBytes(salt);
    //return salt
    return salt.toString();
}
```

Stack trace:
    java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:6313)
    at ServerInterface.ChangeSQLPassword(ServerInterface.java:585)
    at ServerInterface.access$300(ServerInterface.java:68)
    at ServerInterface$2.actionPerformed(ServerInterface.java:277)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Failed.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can't mean much else: you're trying to reuse a closed statement. At what line is the exception being thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are double-using `sta3`: Try

```
concat = concat.concat(...
Statement sta4 = conn.createStatement();
sta4.executeUpdate(concat);
```